# Wordpress custom code pure php

Tags: php, wordpress

**Problem**

I can't find a plugin that suit my need. I want a form that can add a member, and save to the database and query all of it and it can export via csv format. I use Insert PHP plugins and add pure php code in my page, but it won't work. Can somebody please help me? Thank you.

**Code**

```
[insert_php]
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $field1 = $_POST['name'];
    $field2 = $_POST['email'];
    $field3 = $_POST['address'];
    $field4 = date("M d,Y H:i:s");

    $wpdb = prepare("INSERT INTO backend-member (field1,field2,field3,field4) VALUES (:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4)");

    $wpdb->bindParam(':field1', $field1);
    $wpdb->bindParam(':field2', $field2);  
    $wpdb->bindParam(':field3', $field3); 
    $wpdb->bindParam(':field4', $field4);
    $wpdb->execute();
}
[/insert_php]

<form action="" method="POST">
<ul class="form-style-1">
  <li><label>Navn <span class="required">*</span></label><input class="field-long" name="field1" type="text" placeholder="Navn" /></li>
  <li><label>Mobil<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input class="field-long" name="field2" type="text" /></li>
  <li><label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
<input class="field-long" name="field3" type="email" /></li>
  <li><label>Facebook<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input class="field-long" name="field4" type="text" /></li>
  <li><input name="save" type="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: [This might help](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-snippets/)

Comment: thank you. i will try this one, i hope this is the way to solve my problem.

Comment: @Und3rTow i followed all the instruction in that plugin. it is possible to insert the data to database using my php code?

Comment: As long as your PHP is valid and runs without error, then inserting the data should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a shortcode and use that instead.

[Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: Why would you want to create a shortcode for inserting stuff into a database? Shortcodes are for replacments inside the content and should not be used to perform database inserts.

Comment: Inserting pure php is the same thing just in another hand :)

Comment: ok, then after? what next? how do i send the data to database and query it to the page? please help me/ explain more. i am new in wordpress

Comment: @T.Ilciukas okay i got it. i completed insert php code.. I have a problem, how do i insert the data to database?

Comment: @JovelMarkDiaz use wpdb function for that.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: @T.Ilciukas thank you. i already solve this problem. using $wpdb reference, thank you.

Comment: @JovelMarkDiaz Glad to hear :)